# Deriving an attribute from ManyToMany-linked objects

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've got two entities `A` and `B` with a many-to-many relationship. Entity `A` has an enum attribute `C` saved as string. Now I want `B` to have the maximum `C` from all connected `A`s.

I could write a JPA query easily, but where do you put queries that span over two entities? I'm working with DAOs that only work with one entity at a time. I thought about getting all `A`s from a `B` in a loop in Java so that it all runs in one transaction, but I think this might result in many selects where only one is needed.

Any recommendation is welcome.

**UPDATE:**

Consider the following example:

a jewelry store has a OneToMany relationship to jewels. Now I'd like to have a transitive attribute "biggestPieceSize" which reflects the max() value of the connected entities' size attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping is highly inefficient solution because it unnecessarily fetches to much unneeded data from the db.

In general, write a JPQL query, pick any entity involved in the query and place the query into the DAO class for that entity.

Since you are returning `B` here, it seems to me that placing the query in `DAO<B>` is the most natural choice.

Comment: I now have a query that sets the attribute for a given entity object. However, do I need to run that for every single object explicitly?

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak I suggest you ask a separate question about it, since it is not related to the issue in this question.